# изменение экрана в зависимости от времени суток андроид

Tags: android, activity, datetime, timestamp

Задание в горизонтальной ориентации создать две колонки: одна для кнопок другая для отображения результата нажатия этих кнопок ("была нажата кнопка A, кнопка Б, кнопка С"). 
НО чтобы в определенные часы (с 9:00 до 14:00 например) был один список кнопок для нажатия , а в другие другой.
Собственно вопрос как это сделать? То есть без часов у меня проблем не возникает - в одной части экрана леплю кнопки в другой какой-нибдь текствью и все...А с часами как? как все это заместить таким же экраном, но с другим набором кнопок?
Подскажите пожалуйста в общих чертах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Можно создать кнопки на все случаи жизни, а потом, в зависимости от текущего времени, часть этих кнопок скрыть при помощи setVisibility(View.GONE), при этом кнопки не просто исчезнут, а еще и не будут занимать места на экране
2. Можно создать несколько различных лейаутов, а в зависимости от времени, показывать нужный, выбирая его через setContentView()

Самый интересный вариант, это когда мы в зависимости от текущего времени расчитываем какой-то интересный хеш (или что-то еще с лавинным эффектов для лучшего распределения бит), а в зависимости от результирующих бит включаем/выключаем кнопочки. При каждом запуске приложение будет выглядеть по разному. Настоящий кошмар для тестировщика готов!

Текущее время можно получить при помощи классов Date и System